# How to override the cli name in argparse -h usage information?

Tags: python, argparse, appimage

I am bundling my python app into an .AppImage file. Now, when I run it with flag `-h` I would expect it to print something along these lines:

```
$ ./mytool.AppImage -h
usage: mytool [-h] [-d DIR] [-f] [-e] [BLA [BLA ...]]
...
```

But due to the nature of the AppImage bundling process I get:

```
$ ./mytool.AppImage -h
usage: AppRun [-h] [-d DIR] [-f] [-e] [BLA [BLA ...]]
...
```

That is, `AppRun` instead of `mytool`.

So my question is:

How can I force override the app name so that regardless of how the app is called it will always print the same name in the usage string?

Comment: Try the `prog` parameter when creating the parser.

Comment: Ah nice. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per hpaulj's comment, this can solved by simply setting the `prog` parameter of the `argparse.ArgumentParser` constructor:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='mytool',
        description='Some description...'
)
```